# Promise.all() and .then issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to do some stack operations in node.js
Basically i'm trying to get the code below working. The problem is that the pop happens before the push and I get the "empty stack" error.

```
const stack = new stack;

findAllOfA()
.then(allA => {                         //first then
  return Promise.all(allA.map(A => {
  stack.push(a);
  });
})
.then(() => {                           //second then
  var topA = stack.pop();
  //Do some things with topA
}
```

I think i'm supposed to return something from within the function in map but I dont know what to return to make sure the first then is fullfilled before second then is invoked.

It is psudocode (real code is pretty cluttered)
Here comes the real code (beware)

```
const catStack = new dataStructures.Stack();
  let layer = 0;

  //Generic while promise function
  function promiseWhile(predicate, action) {
    console.log('in while');
    function loop() {
      if (!predicate) return;
      return Promise.resolve(action()).then(loop);
    }
    return Promise.resolve().then(loop);
  }

  categoryFacade.findAllMainCategories()
    .then((mainCategories) => {
      return Promise.all(mainCategories.map((mainCategory) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(mainCategory.name, null, 0));
        catStack.push(mainCategory);
        return mainCategory;
      }));
    })
  .then(promiseWhile(!catStack.empty(), function() {
    console.log('in action');
    let nextToProcess = catStack.pop();
    layer += 2;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(nextToProcess.name, null, layer));
    return categoryFacade.findAllChildrenOf(nextToProcess.name)
    .then(allChildren => Promise.all(allChildren.map((child) => {
      catStack.push(child);
      return child;
    })));
  }))
```

Comment: `const stack = new stack;` makes no sense -- it will produce a parsing error. There are also closing parentheses missing. Also, `A` and `a`?? But after those corrections, the code may still be weird, but it will produce the push before the pop. Please provide a snippet that reproduces your problem.

Comment: too many syntactical errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.all()` accepts value or promises. So you can just return `a`.

Is your actual code more complicated than the example you show?

I don't see a need to do it with `Promise.all()`

```
findAllOfA().then(allA => {
  allA.map(stack.push)
}).then(() => {
  const topA = stack.pop()
})

// or
findAllOfA().then(allA => allA.shift()).then(topA => {...})
```

If your first `then()` involves some async function, you will have a promise object at hand for each entry in `allA`, you just need to return that promise for `Promise.all()` to wait for.

EDIT: Your problem is that your `promiseWhile()` is executed at evaluation, not when the `then()` is called.

All you need it `.then(() => promiseWhile(...))`

Comment: return a still makes second then go before first then

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't really make sense.  You use `Promise.all()` on  an array of promises.  But, that is not what you're passing it.

In addition, you are missing some parens to properly contain the `.map()`.  The code as you show it won't even get through the Javascript parser.

And as mentioned elsewhere, `const stack = new stack` is also wrong.  You would  need to use a different variable name than the constructor name.

To show you the proper code, we need to understand what is and isn't promises in your code.

If `allA` is an array of promises that resolves to a result you want, then you can just do:

```
Promise.all(allA).then(results => {
   // process resolved results of all the promises in allA array
});
```

If `allA` is an array of data that you want to call some function on that returns a promise (which is usually why you combine `Promise.all()` with `.map()`, then you would do something like this:

```
Promise.all(allA.map(A => { someFunctionThatReturnsPromise(A) }))
  .then(results => {
      // process results here
  }).catch(err => {
      // process error here
  });
```

And, **if there are no async operations at all here**, then just use `.map()` by itself:

```
let results = allA.map(A => {
    // process A here
    return some processed version of A
});

// process results here
```

Or, if all you want to do is to iterate your array, then just use for/of and you can do anything you want in that loop.

```
for (let A of allA) {
   // do whatever you want with A here
}
```

Comment: I don't have a function "someFunctionThatReturnsPromise(A)" all I want to do is push A to a stack. Returning som processed version of A still doesn't help since second then is still executed before first then.

Comment: @HenrikStåhlberg - If you have no asynchronous operation at all here, then there's no reason to use `Promise.all()` at all.  Just use `.map()` or `.forEach()` by itself.  We can't really help you further with `Promise.all()` until you show us where you have promises and where you have asynchronous operations!  By definition `p.then() is asynchronous which messed up sequenced code.  So, DON'T use it if you don't have asynchronous code already.  And, then when you do use it for async code, you have to use it properly.  See what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: @HenrikStåhlberg - Oh, I see you edited your question without telling anyone a little while ago.  Nevermind.  It turns out that your original question (which I spent a fair amount of time attempting to answer) had nothing to do with the issues in the actual real code.  Please post your REAL code at the beginning next time so we all waste a lot less time trying to understand the REAL problem.